# Getting the properties of a GeoJSON data layer in Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When loading a geoJSON file into a Google Map as a data layer, how does one access the properties of the data layer itself?

I know how to [access the individual properties](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-dynamic), like `posts_here` in the below example. What I'm looking to get is the properties for the layer itself- in this example, `maxPosts`.

```
$.getJSON("http://example.com/posts/grid.json" + location.search, function (data) {
        grid = map_canvas.data.addGeoJson(data);
        map_canvas.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
        return /** @type {google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */({
            strokeWeight: Math.log(feature.getProperty('posts_here')),
        });
    })
});
```

Example of the `grid.json` I'm loading:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [-58,-35],
                        [-58,-34],
                        [-57,-34],
                        [-57,-35],
                        [-58,-35]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "posts_here": "177"
            }
        }
    ],
    "properties": {
        "maxPosts": "177"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The API does only parse the `features`-array of a FeatureCollection, when you want to access additional properties you must implement it on your own.

Based on the given code it isn't complicated, because the geoJson is accessible as object via `data` inside the `$.getJSON`-callback, you may simply access the property via

```
data.properties.maxPosts
```

Comment: You've got it. Lesson to self: console.log() EVERYTHING.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to use [getFeatureById(id:number|string)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data) to access information you've added from your geoJSON.